# Need help recognizing kanji

Tags: kanji

[image]

I'm having a lot of trouble with this one, due the blurriness of the text and the fact that I'm struggling to recognize the radicals. Thank you in advance^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty it is the Kanji for "fly"

http://www.japanese-language.aiyori.org/kanji-fly.html